# Gosu Installation Error

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I'm trying to set up the Ruby for kids tutorial, and am completely stuck on the first step. Something with my GOSU GEM instalation is wring. 
Whenever I try and run the main file as requested I get this error:

> internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require:29:in require': no such file to
>   load -- gosu (LoadError)    from
>   internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in require'
>
> from main.rb:1:in `main'

I have run the `$ sudo gem install gosu` many times in different locations, upon studying the outcome I've located this:

```
ERROR:  Error installing gosu:

ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/carlosamengual/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

The Gosu gem requires some libraries to be installed system-wide.
See the following site for a list:
https://github.com/jlnr/gosu/wiki/Getting-Started-on-Linux

I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong. I've visited the site it says, but I believe, since it is a ruby project I don't need anything else? Can anyone advise as to how to fix it?

Comment: What operating system are you running (from your post I'm assuming a Linux variant, but which one?)

Comment: did you check out the gosu installation notes for OSX?

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue whilst installing on OS X 10.9.4 although am not sure the version has much to do with it, but ruby version is **ruby-2.1.2**

To resolve this, I installed these additional dependencies for Gosu which fixed the problem:

```
brew install sdl2 libogg libvorbis
```

Then run **gem install gosu** as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you using rbenv or install ruby by homebrew. Rvm is not compatible with gosu. 
Install homebrew: https://brew.sh/ .

Then:

```
brew install sdl2
brew install libogg libvorbis
brew unlink imagemagick
brew install imagemagick@6 && brew link imagemagick@6 --force
```

And have fun!

look at: https://github.com/gosu/gosu/wiki/Getting-Started-on-OS-X

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ruby [Gosu](https://www.libgosu.org/) on OSX, you might want to go here:

https://github.com/gosu/gosu/wiki/Getting-Started-on-OS-X

For what it is worth, I'm currently using Ubuntu 14 with Ruby 2.3 and using rvm 1.11.3.9 I have downloaded gosu 0.10.8 and successfully gotten a gosu window to load. I had the same problem while starting off with Ruby Gosu and using "bundler" in the project directory took care of the gem dependency. In addition to visiting this website:

https://github.com/gosu/gosu/wiki/Getting-Started-on-Linux

and after entering this in the command line:

```
user@ubuntu:~/Ruby/gosu_project$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libsdl2-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev libpango1.0-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libfreeimage-dev libopenal-dev libsndfile-dev
```

```
user@ubuntu:~/Ruby/gosu_project$ gem install gosu
```

I also had to invoke:

`user@ubuntu:~/Ruby/gosu_project$`**bundle**

http://bundler.io/ - also works with MacOSX...

per: https://github.com/gosu/gosu/wiki/ruby-tutorial

This gosu file:

```
# basic Gosu: gui test file

require 'gosu'
require_relative 'gosu_test.rb'

class TestWindow < Gosu::Window   # <-- inherits from Gosu Window Super class

  def initialize
    super 640, 480, false         # <-- width, height, fullscreen = false
    self.caption = "successful gosu test window"
  end

  def update
  end

  def draw
  end

end


TestWindow.new.show
```

...loads a 640x480 window

```
user@ubuntu:~/Ruby/gosu_project$ ruby gosu_test.rb
```